# Duplicate Filenames Being Saved Powershell Search and Replace Excel

Tags: powershell

I created a function, that when called in my script will search through recursively in a directory and all subdirectories for a specific string in Excel files.  With the help of this community, I have my script working for .config files, but I am stumped with this Excel and why it is saving the file path twice for each file that had a change made (string found to replace):

```
Function Get-ExcelFunction () {
   
    $rootDir = Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter *.xlsx -Recurse

    ForEach ($dir in $rootDir) { 
        $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
        $Excel.visible = $false
        $Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($dir.FullName)

        ForEach ($sheet in $Workbook.Worksheets) {
            $Range = $sheet.Range("A1:EZ800").EntireColumn #Range of Cells to look at
            $Search = $Range.find($oldString)
            
            if ($null -ne $Search) {
                $FirstAddress = $search.Address
                do {
                    $Search.value() = $Search.value().Replace($oldString, $newString) #String to Update
                    $Search = $Range.FindNext($Search)
                } while ( $null -ne $Search -and $Search.Address -ne $FirstAddress)
                $dir.FullName >> $filePathName #Write the path to where the file was changed to a change log file
            }
        }
        $WorkBook.Save()
        $WorkBook.Close()
        [void]$Excel.quit()
    }
}
```

This is the line where I am getting the path and adding to the txt file to save.

> $dir.FullName >> $filePathName

My output file to show what files got changed:

> C:\Users\Tara\Documents_Local\ReplaceEmailPowershell\TestFolder\20230501_HIST_BGE_ELE_GAS - Copy.xlsx
> C:\Users\Tara\Documents_Local\ReplaceEmailPowershell\TestFolder\20230501_HIST_BGE_ELE_GAS - Copy.xlsx
> C:\Users\Tara\Documents_Local\ReplaceEmailPowershell\TestFolder\20230501_HIST_BGE_ELE_GAS.xlsx
> C:\Users\Tara\Documents_Local\ReplaceEmailPowershell\TestFolder\20230501_HIST_BGE_ELE_GAS.xlsx
> C:\Users\Tara\Documents_Local\ReplaceEmailPowershell\TestFolder2\TestingFile.xlsx
> C:\Users\Tara\Documents_Local\ReplaceEmailPowershell\TestFolder2\TestingFile.xlsx

Any pointers grealy appreciated!

Comment: If you don't want to log to the file for each worksheet found then move the `$dir.FullName >> $filePathName` line outside of the inner worksheet foreach loop, maybe just above `$WorkBook.Save()`.

Comment: @jfrmilner That is where I had it prior and noticed the duplicate writings to the file.  I moved it inside **if ($null -ne $Search)** and thought that would have solved the duplication, but it did not.  I borrowed some of the code I am using and think now I see my issue.  I need to figure out how to only copy path when a match is found to replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why there were 2 entries for each of the files that were updated.  There were 2 sheets for each of the workbooks that had a match for the word to update.  I figured out how to append the sheet name to the complete file path.  See the full working code below:

```
Function Get-ExcelFunction () {
   
    $rootDir = Get-ChildItem $dirPath -Filter *.xlsx -Recurse

    ForEach ($dir in $rootDir) { 
        $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
        $Excel.visible = $false
        $Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($dir.FullName)

        ForEach ($sheet in $Workbook.Worksheets) {
            $Range = $sheet.Range("A1:EZ800").EntireColumn #Range of Cells to look at
            $Search = $Range.find($oldString)
            if ($null -ne $Search) {
                $FirstAddress = $search.Address
                do {
                    $Search.value() = $Search.value().Replace($oldString, $newString) #String to Update
                    $Search = $Range.FindNext($Search)
                } while ( $null -ne $Search -and $Search.Address -ne $FirstAddress) 
                $sheetName = $sheet.Name #Grab the name of the sheet that is being updated
                $dir.FullName + "_$sheetName" >> $filePathName #Write the path to where the file was changed to a change log file
            }
        }
        
        $WorkBook.Save()
        $WorkBook.Close()
        [void]$Excel.quit()
    }
}
```